# controller and method translate in htaccess mod rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some URL:

```
index.php?controller=user&method=show&id=7
```

in this URL: controller,method and show, are my keys
user, show and 7 are some kind of value

I would like translate URL to:

```
index.php?user/show/7
```

Is there any posibilities to translate this URL in .htaccess file?
Now, my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Cobbler/index.php
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the benefit of this but you can replace your current code by this one

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Cobbler/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . ./ [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?controller=%1&method=%2&id=%3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: great. Is possible to delete also index.php from URL?